# Multi level selecting and function in a Oracle IQ database

Tags: oracle

There i a simplified table myowner.mydable with at least columns order_nr,the_days, and i us a multilevel select-query

```
select * from (
    select
```

The sum(..) function does not work in a inner select-query. How to do use a function in a inner select???

```
(select sum(the_days) from myowner.mydable where order_nr=confnr) "thedays",--this is a line 4
confnr as order_nr
from (
    select order_nr as confnr,the_days from myowner.mydable WHERE order_nr='5276751'
) as t
union all
```

And there i get an another order_nr

```
    select
        (select sum(the_days) from myowner.mydable where order_nr=confnr) "thedays",
        confnr as order_nr
    from (
        select order_nr as confnr,the_days from myowner.mydable WHERE order_nr='5276751'
    ) as t

) as t2
```

Select (.....) as t works. But select ((.....) as t union all (.....) as t) as t2 gives an error:

```
Could not execute statement.
Feature, scalar value subquery (at line 4) outside of a top level SELECT
list, is not supported. 
-- (opt_Select.cxx 2238)
SQLCODE=-1001030, ODBC 3 State="HY000"
Line 1, column 1
```

How to get rid from the error?

Comment: What is your oracle version? Can you show full text of query? My simple example works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/37421/0

Comment: Your query gives also error:

Could not execute statement.
Syntax error near '(end of line)' on line 9
SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3 State="42000"
Line 1, column 1

How to determine a version of oracle?

Comment: also select * from v$version does not work.

Comment: Wait, are you using ODBC? How did you execute my query? Can you do it using SQL*Plus? I don't remember exactly, but it seems I had heard once that ODBC can parse SQL queries and throw exceptions without sending query  to server. Also, error text that you wrote - it is NOT oracle message.

Comment: 10g version of IQ if i heard. I use it in a ODBC (Sybase Central) and Interactive Sql. And in a customer's remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need execute this query often, you can try to create view based on this query and use it.

Also, your subquery looks strange. This:

```
select
    (select sum(the_days) from myowner.mydable where order_nr=confnr) "thedays",
    confnr as order_nr
from (
    select order_nr as confnr,the_days from myowner.mydable WHERE order_nr='5276751'
) as t
```

is equal to this:

```
select sum(the_days), order_nr from myowner.mydable where order_nr = '5276751'
group by order_nr
```

**UPD** Full query you can transform like this:

```
select t.category, t.def_or_indef, t.book_date, t.book_code, t.revenue, 
       t2.conf_nr,
       t2.mydays,
       t.revenue / t2.mydays
  from (select  category, def_or_indef, book_date, book_code,
        revenue, 
        confnr as conf_nr
      from (select CASE WHEN status = 'status1' OR status = 'status2' THEN 'category1' ELSE 'category2' END AS category,
              CASE WHEN status = 'status1' OR status = 'status2' THEN 'definite' ELSE 'indefinite' END AS def_or_indef,
              book_date, 
              book_code, 
              revenue, 
              conf_nr as confnr
          from myowner.mydable 
        WHERE days > 0 
          AND book_date IS NOT NULL 
          AND DATE(dateadd(year,-1,dateadd(day,-day(today()),today()))) < book_date 
          AND book_date <=  date(dateadd(day,-day(today()),today()))) as t
        union all
        select ..  from ( select .. WHERE ..  AND DATE(dateadd(day,-day(today()),today())) < resv_date and resv_date < today() 
         ) as t,
  (select conf_nr, sum(days) as mydays
    from myowner.mydable 
   group by conf_nr) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

I give a real query:

```
select * from (
    select
        category, def_or_indef, book_date, book_code,
        (select sum(days) from myowner.mydable where conf_nr=confnr) as mydays,
        revenue, confnr as conf_nr,
        revenue / (select sum(days) from myowner.mydable where conf_nr=confnr) as adr
    from (
        select
            CASE WHEN status = 'status1' OR status = 'status2' THEN 'category1' ELSE 'category2' END AS category,
            CASE WHEN status = 'status1' OR status = 'status2' THEN 'definite' ELSE 'indefinite' END AS def_or_indef,
            book_date, book_code, revenue, conf_nr as confnr
        from myowner.mydable 
        WHERE days > 0 AND book_date IS NOT NULL AND
            DATE(dateadd(year,-1,dateadd(day,-day(today()),today()))) < book_date AND book_date <=  date(dateadd(day,-day(today()),today()))
    ) as t
    union all
    select ..  from ( select .. WHERE ..  AND
        DATE(dateadd(day,-day(today()),today())) < resv_date and resv_date < today()
    ) as t
) as t2
```

Can you give working equal to this?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something, but why you need your outer `select * from (...) t2`? If you remove it, will it work?

Comment: I dried also it without select ... t2. It work slowly. The table contains several millions rows.

Comment: This outer select can't give you any acceleration. It will work slowly too.